# Rails 4 asset pipeline not linking to css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Okay, I've been having this problem for quite a while now and I can't figure it out. I have a bare-bones app with one controller called 'home' and one action called 'index'. I am using the default layout 'application.html.erb', and in that layout I am using the following:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

my application.css file contains the following code below the manifest portion:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and my index file only contains the following snippet:

```
<p>This is my content!</p>
```

When I try to access my page, I get the following error:

```
JSON::ParserError in Home#index
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: Show the code for your `HomeController`'s `index` method.

Comment: Okay I edited my post @p4sh4

Comment: When you access your page, below the "JSON::ParserError" you will also get a bunch of lines called the stack trace. What are those lines?

Comment: Something in your app is non-standard. One suggestion is to simple start with a fresh app. Or, show above what you have changed, likely in your ApplicationController or Gemfile.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to install nodejs. Thanks anyway!